# How to change the active mdi child?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

Well this maybe is simple but I cannot nail it.
I have a win forms application with a from as  Mdi Container with **n** mdi childs.
How to set ActiveMdiChild ?
For example i have 4 mdi childs (0,1,2,3) and i want to pass the appropriate data to each one...but only the active gets the data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To activate a specific MDI child, you can use [`ActivateMdiChild`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activatemdichild(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the MDI parent and pass the child to activate. For example:

```
 this.ActivateMdiChild(this.MdiChildren[0]);
```

> [**ActivateMdiChild (Form)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activatemdichild(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> Activates the MDI child of a form.
>
> If the form parameter is already the active MDI child form, then the
>   `ActivateMdiChild` method simply returns. If form is not null, then it
>   is set to be the active MDI child form. Whether the form parameter is
>   null or not, `ActivateMdiChild` raises the `MdiChildActivate` event.

Comment: Is not working....i guess because this inside a multi threading method where an array of BlockingCollection is iterated and i try to pass the appropiate BC to each of the childs....i get: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: It's totally a different question and I prefer to keep the answer untouched and clean. But when you are calling the method from a different thread than UI thread, you can use `this.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.ActivateMdiChild(this.MdiChildren[0]);  }));`

Comment: First two [frequent questions of WinForms tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms?sort=frequent) answers updating UI from another thread.

Comment: I didn't thought that it will require Invoke....my bad...i am afraid code still doesn't work....:(

Comment: The solution is correct....i have some issues when i am passing the data....thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
  foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (frm is Form1)
            {
                Form frmChild = this.ActiveMdiChild;
                frmChild .Show();
            }
        }
```

If the child have different form names, you can just have if statement to check if this is the form you are checking then set it as your acitvemdichild.

Comment: I am not looking for the ActiveMdiChild...i am looking for changing it..

Comment: Is the mdi childs have different Form names? Or sometimes they are the same?